# Trouble reading documentation Interface Definition

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm trying to figure out how a Redux createStore function works(what parameters it accepts) with enhancers from the documentation.

what I understand is, "`sayHiOnDispatch`" takes a "`createStore`" function as a parameter and creates a closure around the inner anonymous function which accepts 3 arguments,

```
rootReducer, preloadedState, enhancers
```

finally, it return an object `{...store,dispatch:newDispatch}`.
what I don't understand is: 1)Where is `sayHiOnDispatch` is being called from?
2)How the anonymous function is getting called?
3)What variable receives the return value of `return { ...store, dispatch: newDispatch }`
4)What calls the `newDispatch` functions?
5)How can I understand the function structure(params, return values, etc..) from the Interface Definition?

```html
export type StoreEnhancer<Ext = {}, StateExt = never> = (
  next: StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<Ext, StateExt>
) => StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<Ext, StateExt>
export type StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<Ext = {}, StateExt = never> = <
  S = any,
  A extends Action = AnyAction
>(
  reducer: Reducer<S, A>,
  preloadedState?: PreloadedState<S>
) => Store<ExtendState<S, StateExt>, A, StateExt, Ext> & Ext
```

The redux tutorial code.

```html
export const sayHiOnDispatch = (createStore) => {
  return (rootReducer, preloadedState, enhancers) => {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState, enhancers)

    function newDispatch(action) {
      const result = store.dispatch(action)
      console.log('Hi!')
      return result
    }

    return { ...store, dispatch: newDispatch }
  }
}
```

Hopefully, someone will provide a fishing-rod for me to fish the fish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the questions in order:

1. `sayHiOnDispatch` gets called either as `return enhancer(createStore)(reducer, preloadedState)` [inside of `createStore` itself](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/v4.2.0/src/createStore.js#L58), or on the same line as part of a "composed" enhancer (like `compose(applyMiddleware(), sayHiOnDispatch)` )
2. The anonymous function is called on that same line - it's the return value from `enhancer()`
3. The returned `{...store, dispatch: newDispatch}` *is* the actual `store` variable, as in `const store = createStore()`
4. `newDispatch` *is* the actual `store.dispatch` function, so it's called as `store.dispatch(someAction)`
5. Yeah, that is definitely a complex type signature :)  To be honest I wouldn't worry about it - odds are you won't ever end up writing an enhancer yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this along with function currying in redux-middleware really spins the clockwork in my brain.